# Graphical errors for window borders, buttons after update 2017-03-06, 16.04

Tags: nvidia

Yesterday, I added the Sane PPA (scanner drivers), aptitude update+upgrade, and then rebooted when it prompted me to. The reboot didn't finish (it just sat there on the screen with "Ubuntu" and the red/white dots for 15ish minutes), so I power cycled the machine.

Now I see what looks like uninitialized video memory where the window shadows and corner buttons should be:

[image: visual noise instead of shadows]

I'm on a Dell XPS 15" with an NVidia 960M, running the graphics drivers PPA (nvidia-375 375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2), otherwise pretty stock 16.04 in terms of packages.

I can dig up logs of what packages exactly got updated with yesterday's aptitude upgrade, if it's relevant.

My questions:

- Is this a known issue?
- Is there a workaround or fix?
- If not, where is the best place to report the bug?

Edit to add requested info:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics [8086:191b] (rev 06)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Dell Skylake Integrated Graphics [1028:06e4]
```

But FYI there is also:

```
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [10de:139b] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Dell GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [1028:06e4]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
```

Xorg.0.log:

```
    [     5.139] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[     5.139] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     5.139] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     5.139] Current Operating System: Linux xps 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64
[     5.139] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=79df2908-59b6-47bf-9138-c9f552866024 ro RESUME=UUID=/dev/nvme0n1p3 quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[     5.139] Build Date: 02 November 2016  10:06:10PM
[     5.139] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     5.139] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[     5.139]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     5.139] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     5.139] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar  8 09:34:26 2017
[     5.139] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     5.139] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     5.140] (==) ServerLayout "layout"
[     5.140] (**) |-->Screen "nvidia" (0)
[     5.140] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     5.141] (**) |   |-->Device "nvidia"
[     5.141] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "nvidia"
[     5.141] (==) No monitor specified for screen "nvidia".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     5.141] (**) |-->Inactive Device "intel"
[     5.141] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     5.141] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     5.141] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     5.141] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     5.141] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     5.141]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.141] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     5.141]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.141] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     5.141]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.141] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     5.141]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.141] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     5.141]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.141] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     5.141] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     5.141] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     5.141] (II) Loader magic: 0x56154a22ddc0
[     5.141] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     5.141]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     5.141]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[     5.141]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[     5.141]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[     5.141] (++) using VT number 7

[     5.141] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     5.142] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     5.142] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[     5.245] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:191b:1028:06e4 rev 6, Mem @ 0xdb000000/16777216, 0x70000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[     5.245] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:139b:1028:06e4 rev 162, Mem @ 0xdc000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, 0xc0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     5.245] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[     5.245] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[     5.245] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     5.246] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[     5.255] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.255]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.255]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     5.256] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  375.39  Tue Jan 31 19:37:12 PST 2017
[     5.256] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     5.256] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[     5.257] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.257]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.257]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.258] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     5.258] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     5.258] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.258]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[     5.258]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.258]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[     5.258] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  375.39  Tue Jan 31 19:13:22 PST 2017
[     5.258] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[     5.258] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     5.258] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     5.258] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     5.258] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     5.259] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.259]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.259]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.259] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[     5.259] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[     5.259] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[     5.259] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.259]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.259]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.259] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[     5.259] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[     5.259] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[     5.261] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card1
[     5.261] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "nvidia" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     5.261] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.261] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     5.261] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.261] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     5.261] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
[     5.261] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
[     5.261] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
[     5.261] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     5.447] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 960M (GM107-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[     5.447] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[     5.447] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 82.07.82.00.2a
[     5.447] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[     5.447] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[     5.447] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
[     5.447] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
[     5.447] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[     5.447] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[     5.447] (==) modeset(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.447] (**) modeset(G0): Option "AccelMethod" "None"
[     5.447] (==) modeset(G0): RGB weight 888
[     5.447] (==) modeset(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.447] (**) modeset(G0): glamor disabled
[     5.447] (II) modeset(G0): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
[     5.447] (II) modeset(G0): Output eDP-1-1 has no monitor section
[     5.449] (II) modeset(G0): Output DP-1-1 has no monitor section
[     5.576] (II) modeset(G0): Output HDMI-1-1 has no monitor section
[     5.578] (II) modeset(G0): Output DP-1-2 has no monitor section
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Output HDMI-1-2 has no monitor section
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): EDID for output eDP-1-1
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Manufacturer: SHP  Model: 143e  Serial#: 0
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Year: 2015  Week: 40
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): EDID Version: 1.4
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Digital Display Input
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): 8 bits per channel
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 35  vert.: 19
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Gamma: 2.20
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Default color space is primary color space
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Preferred mode is native pixel format and refresh rate
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): redX: 0.660 redY: 0.328   greenX: 0.203 greenY: 0.722
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): blueX: 0.146 blueY: 0.048   whiteX: 0.306 whiteY: 0.328
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): clock: 533.2 MHz   Image Size:  346 x 194 mm
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): h_active: 3840  h_sync: 3888  h_sync_end 3920 h_blank_end 4000 h_border: 0
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): v_active: 2160  v_sync: 2163  v_sync_end 2168 v_blanking: 2222 v_border: 0
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  7PHPT\82LQ156D1
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Unknown vendor-specific block 0
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): EDID (in hex):
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  00ffffffffffff004d103e1400000000
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  28190104a52313780e0394a95434b825
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  0c4e5400000001010101010101010101
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  0101010101014dd000a0f0703e803020
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  35005ac2100000180000000000000000
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  00000000000000000000000000fe0037
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  50485054824c51313536443100000000
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0):  0002410328001200000b010a20200032
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Printing probed modes for output eDP-1-1
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "3840x2160"x60.0  533.25  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2168 2222 -hsync -vsync (133.3 kHz eP)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "2048x1536"x60.0  266.95  2048 2200 2424 2800  1536 1537 1540 1589 -hsync +vsync (95.3 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1440"x60.0  234.00  1920 2048 2256 2600  1440 1441 1444 1500 -hsync +vsync (90.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1856x1392"x60.0  218.30  1856 1952 2176 2528  1392 1393 1396 1439 -hsync +vsync (86.4 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1792x1344"x60.0  204.80  1792 1920 2120 2448  1344 1345 1348 1394 -hsync +vsync (83.7 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1200"x60.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x59.9  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1600x1024"x60.2  103.12  1600 1600 1656 1664  1024 1024 1029 1030 +hsync +vsync (62.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  122.00  1400 1488 1640 1880  1050 1052 1064 1082 +hsync +vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1360x768"x59.8   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   72.00  1360 1408 1440 1520  768 771 781 790 +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1152x864"x60.0   81.62  1152 1216 1336 1520  864 865 868 895 -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x120.1  133.47  1024 1100 1212 1400  768 768 770 794 doublescan -hsync +vsync (95.3 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "960x720"x120.0  117.00  960 1024 1128 1300  720 720 722 750 doublescan -hsync +vsync (90.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "928x696"x120.1  109.15  928 976 1088 1264  696 696 698 719 doublescan -hsync +vsync (86.4 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "896x672"x120.0  102.40  896 960 1060 1224  672 672 674 697 doublescan -hsync +vsync (83.7 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "960x600"x120.0   77.00  960 984 1000 1040  600 601 604 617 doublescan +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "960x540"x120.0   69.25  960 984 1000 1040  540 541 544 555 doublescan +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "800x600"x120.0   81.00  800 832 928 1080  600 600 602 625 doublescan +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "840x525"x120.0   73.12  840 892 980 1120  525 526 529 544 doublescan -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "840x525"x119.8   59.50  840 864 880 920  525 526 529 540 doublescan +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "800x512"x120.3   51.56  800 800 828 832  512 512 514 515 doublescan +hsync +vsync (62.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "700x525"x120.0   61.00  700 744 820 940  525 526 532 541 doublescan +hsync +vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "640x512"x120.0   54.00  640 664 720 844  512 512 514 533 doublescan +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "720x450"x119.8   53.25  720 760 836 952  450 451 454 467 doublescan -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "640x480"x120.0   54.00  640 688 744 900  480 480 482 500 doublescan +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "680x384"x119.6   42.38  680 716 784 888  384 385 390 399 doublescan -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "680x384"x119.9   36.00  680 704 720 760  384 385 390 395 doublescan +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "576x432"x120.1   40.81  576 608 668 760  432 432 434 447 doublescan -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "512x384"x120.0   32.50  512 524 592 672  384 385 388 403 doublescan -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "400x300"x120.6   20.00  400 420 484 528  300 300 302 314 doublescan +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "400x300"x112.7   18.00  400 412 448 512  300 300 301 312 doublescan +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[     5.704] (II) modeset(G0): Modeline "320x240"x120.1   12.59  320 328 376 400  240 245 246 262 doublescan -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[     5.707] (II) modeset(G0): EDID for output DP-1-1
[     5.832] (II) modeset(G0): EDID for output HDMI-1-1
[     5.834] (II) modeset(G0): EDID for output DP-1-2
[     5.960] (II) modeset(G0): EDID for output HDMI-1-2
[     5.960] (II) modeset(G0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[     5.960] (==) modeset(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[     5.960] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     5.960] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     5.960] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     5.960] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.960]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.960]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.960] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[     5.960] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[     5.960] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[     5.960] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.960]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.1.0
[     5.960]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.960] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     5.961] (==) modeset(G0): Backing store enabled
[     5.961] (==) modeset(G0): Silken mouse enabled
[     5.961] (II) modeset(G0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[     5.961] (==) modeset(G0): DPMS enabled
[     5.961] (WW) modeset(G0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" is not used
[     5.961] (WW) modeset(G0): Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" is not used
[     6.252] (II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[     6.252] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[     6.254] (WW) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: AC power state information is not available under
[     6.254] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     /sys/class/power_supply/ , nor under
[     6.255] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/
[     6.269] (II) NVIDIA(0): Built-in logo is bigger than the screen.
[     6.269] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[     6.272] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[     6.272] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[     6.272] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     6.272] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[     6.272] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     6.272] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     6.272] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     6.272] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     6.272] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[     6.272] (--) RandR disabled
[     6.274] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[     6.275] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[     6.275] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[     6.275] (II) modeset(G0): Damage tracking initialized
[     6.299] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
(snip)
```

Truncated for length (body text limited to 30k characters); full log here: https://gist.github.com/elistevens/2b2d48dfb9eac15dffed2b97e4ef56a8

Edit 2: NVidia driver version `375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2`, uname -a reports `Linux xps 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Does the issue persist after another reboot? Could you please include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA` and the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` in your question? Thanks.

Comment: The issue does persist through reboots. Thanks for taking a look.  :)

Comment: Can you try to remove the Sane PPA (`sudo ppa-purge <PPA>`) and check if the problem persists? You can also boot a different kernel versions from before the first occurrence of the issue.

Comment: Should I just remove the PPA, or the packages I installed from there as well?  Also, I should note that currently, putting my laptop to sleep causes it to reboot on wake, so reproducing the graphical issue is now difficult (I didn't think that it required a sleep cycle to happen originally, but now I'm not sure).

Comment: `ppa-purge` disables the PPA and removes or replaces all packages installed from that PPA. If wake-up from suspension doesn't work you should perform a proper shutdown instead and verify the file system integrity. That issue may be related to the graphics driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same. There is a bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1292830

It took me awhile to find it. A quick workaround:

`compiz --replace`

Comment: That does seem to be the issue. `compiz --replace` caused the issue to go away. A bit disheartening that the bug's been open since 2014.

Comment: I had to add the solution to the answer. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I would say that the compiz --replace is more of a workaround rather than a solution since it needs to be done everytime that the window corruption occurs

Comment: I just updated to nvidia-381 this morning, and the issue seems to have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this bug.

[image: A screenshot showing the glitch/bug]

I also have a Nvidia graphics card, a Geforce 440M (not the optimus version)

Using any of the Nvidia drivers results in shown bug. 
Usually it happens after waking from sleep, some times after some application goes full screen.

I can answer your question though. 
How do I get rid of the glitching borders, shadows and buttons? 
Easy. Go to unity tweak tool -> themes, then pick another theme, and then your current theme again, then close the window. 
The glitching is gone. (At least for me)

This is not a definitive solution, as glitching may happen again on the same session. If it does, just repeat the process I stated.

Comment: Any idea where to report the bug?

Comment: Not sure, because to this day I cannot still track the origin. 
I am sure I do not have the PPA you added, so you can take that suspect off your list. 

I am on 16.10, and have updated the kernel, and I believe you have not updated it, so I can take the kernel update off my list. 

Only similarity between our systems is the Nvidia GPU, but having tried all the available versions of the official drivers, I still face this. I don't recall you mentioning trying different drivers so I guess It's not driver related.

Comment: Seen as how my system responds when changing themes, and hets rid of the bug, it may be something gtk related, I am not sure and will get in to this if you can reproduce the "fix" I posted. 

Please try to do so if you come across the glitching again.

I am not that good hunting bugs in linux yet, but your input may help me narrow the scope. 

Thanks.

Comment: Just now, my laptop came up from sleep without rebooting, and the video corruption happened again. Changing the GTK+ dropdown fixed the buttons in the upper left corner of the window bar, but the shadows remain as noise.  uname -a says `Linux xps 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` with nvidia `375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2` from the graphics drivers PPA; I presume you're on something different.

Comment: Changing theme also resets the icon-set, which is undesirable for me. I found that just toggling Window snapping in Unity Tweak Tool got the window shadows refreshed.

I started facing this issue with today's system updates. Before that, I found the shadows+dock broken after restoring from hibernation but just triggering window scale/spread was enough to get them all refreshed.

Comment: Just tried with compiz config and found that toggling show mouse (enable, wait a few seconds, then disable) I got window shadows looking good again. Only issue that remains is the in-between-borders-background of the Desktop Wall thumbnail view, but that's very minor for me. I use an old nVidia graphics card.

Comment: Have any one f you guy tried to replicate this bug with the Noveau driver instead of Nvidia official ones?
Since I updated the kernel and Mesa to 17.02 I had not run into this issue. 
It sucks, because I prefer to use Nvidia propietary drivers. (I game a lot and use Torch and Tensorflow, hence I need my couple of cuda cores)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer, but may help to shed light into the issue.

Some days ago, I installed budgie-remix 32bit on a real old laptop I was giving to a charity.

After installing and in the process of making sure the laptop was usable, grabbing some useful software here and there... well; I grew real fond of the Budgie DE.

I got it up and running in my machine, and since that day (yesterday) I've been able to just close the lid and open it to a fully functional, non-glitching laptop.

My guess here, is that this is rather a Unity related bug rather than a graphics stack issue.

My 2 cents. Many people bash on Unity, I love it. But I love a lot more a glitch-free environment. If you have this bug, try and use another DE. Cannot wait for 18.04!

Comment: Judging from the appearance of the glitchy window corners, it *is* an Nvidia graphics stack issue like this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode It's been happening a lot lately.

Comment: I just updated to nvidia-381 this morning, and the issue seems to have gone away.